# What is the best client side technology which can support and able to render '.cshtml Razor Pages' at client side as?

Tags: razor-pages, asp.net-core-mvc-2.1

What is the best client side technology which can support and able to render '.cshtml Razor Pages' at client side as ?
I have more requirements from client-side perspective.

I don't want to leave C# but the same time

Please suggest.

Comment: (There seems to be something missing in `at client side as ?`.) I think this question [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *4. 

Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: Nothing can render Razor Pages at the client side. It's a server-side technology.